# How to make a disabled button appear same as enabled buttons using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a button which is having a text field which is always disabled. I want that text field to appear as bright as it will appear when the button in enabled.

after Disabling a button they appear dimmer than others and text field follows the same pattern as its a part of it.

Comment: Why is it disabled in the first place then? Your question isn't very clear

Comment: Not getting your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make it the other way around? 
There is a way to omit the disabled-attribute by using a little javascript-code like this:

```
$('button:first').click(function(e){

   if(e.preventDefault){
      e.preventDefault();
   }
   else{
      e.returnValue = false; // IE
   }

});

or

document.querySelectorAll('button')[0].onclick = function(e){

   if(e.preventDefault){
      e.preventDefault();
   }
   else{
      e.returnValue = false; // IE
   }

};
```

The Code above prevents that the button executes default browser behavior like submiting form ingredients to a server. Hope this helps a little bit.

Comment: but still it clicking right ?? but I agree with your answer

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question.

Comment: I didnt aked that question , i said that button is still clicking

Comment: thanks, this is good way to go one step ahead,but it should be not be clickable. If there is a way to do that. at mouse-over event the cursor changes to pointing finger from arrow. That should not happen. Is there a way to disable the mouse-over event for a button?????

Comment: Really?, I tried it myself and the cursor did not change. May be a browser setting that can be switched off?

Comment: I got it...need to use Cursor=default as css style then it will not change , thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `input[type="button"]:disabled`

Or another Idea is do not give disable attribute to button at all. In javascript you can right return false on click of that button.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery:

```
$('input:disabled').css({
    'border-color' : '#990000',
    'color': '#990000'
    //etc
});
```

In CSS you can use the `:disabled` [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) (no-go below IE9 of course):

```
input:disabled {
    border-color: #990000;
    color: #990000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for (with css )

```
<style>
    #btn_disabled 
    {
        color: buttontext;
    }
</style>

<button disabled id='btn_disabled'>Button Disabled</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Disable #x
$( "#x" ).prop( "disabled", true );

// Enable #x
$( "#x" ).prop( "disabled", false );
```